# Manipulating Directories and Images with Medium Trust .NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, directory, virtual-directory, virtualpathprovider

This question:

[Creating directories in medium trust environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387888/creating-directories-in-medium-trust-environment)

Is kind of the same, but the answer didn't really help.

On my website, I have a bunch of product images held within a master directory entitled "Products2" within that are various subdirectories 0/0/0/1, 0/0/0/2 etc which contain the images based on item ID.

I have had a number of issues with

`Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.`

`Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`

In trying to use `DirectoryInfo` and `createDirectory` etc due to permissions.

The site is hosted on shared hosting with Medium Trust.

I have asked my hosting company to set the appropriate permissions on the folder so that I can use these features which are fundamentally required to make my website display images correctly. The guys have done this, but for some reason, the server settings keep reverting and then I'm throwing errors all over the place.

I was pointed to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx

By my hosting providers, but I'm not getting anywhere trying to achieve what I need.

Can someone help me with this?

For example, trying to get a list of images contained within a directory and binding them to an ASP:Repeater:

```
Private Function getThumbnails(ByVal directoryPath As String, mainImg As String) As DataTable

    Dim imgTable As New DataTable("images")
    Dim imageURL As DataColumn = New DataColumn("url")
    imgTable.Columns.Add(imageURL)
    Dim imageID As DataColumn = New DataColumn("id")
    imgTable.Columns.Add(imageID)

    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(directoryPath)
    Dim fileList() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg")

    For Each Image In fileList
        If InStr(Image.Name, "-tb") > 0 And InStr(Image.Name, mainImg) <= 0 Then
            Dim imgDetail As DataRow = imgTable.NewRow()
            Dim theMapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Products2")
            Dim dirUrl = "/Products2" & Replace(Replace(directoryPath, theMapPath, ""), "\", "/")
            Dim imgURL As String = Path.Combine("http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & dirUrl, Image.Name)
            imgURL = Replace(Replace(Replace(imgURL, "dev.", "www."), "~", ""), "admin.", "www.")
            imgDetail.Item("url") = imgURL
            imgDetail.Item("id") = Image.Name
            imgTable.Rows.Add(imgDetail)
        End If
    Next
    Return imgTable
End Function
```

This function receives a directory as a string, the variable `directoryPath` is key to it, and is returned as a `Server.MapPath` generated format, so `D://etc...`

What I am being told is that I need to use relative paths, but having tried various "obvious" options I cannot get the same functionality.

To my mind, this simply means "/Products2/0/0/1/" etc, but that isn't working, I get errors saying that the path is invalid.

To do:

```
Uploading (using saveAs from an HttpPostedFile)
Delete images (File.Delete)
Create Directory (Directory.Create(), from Dim Directory As New DirectoryInfo()
```

And to grab images from a directory and display as per the function above.

How would I go about doing this using `VirtualPathProvider`?

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, I managed this using the [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate](http://SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges). Without this, the code would run under the current user's permissions; here's an ASP.NET version:

[Asp.Net Alternative To SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://%20http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2010/01/aspnet-alternative-to.html.)

The other alternative is to take a look at [custom code access security](https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fsugexp%3Dchrome,mod%3D18%26ix%3Dnh%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3Dasp.net%2520RunWithElevatedPrivileges&q=EgRSrc3iGPv3soEGIhkA8aeDS_thTVEvWSK0Cib4PB6LUZIo05_lMgFy); however if you have little control over the host, then the first solution is probably your best route.

Here's where I used it for a Web Part with SharePoint:

[Create a Web Part with VSeWSS 1.3 - Part II](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/01/25/Create-a-Web-Part-with-VSeWSS-13-Part-II.aspx)

As for the issue with the path being invalid, it should be simple enough to check what's being generated.